# Dockerfile inconsistent caching

Tags: docker, dockerfile

[According to the Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#build-cache), the docker build should cache all of the lines that have not changed.

The problem is, even when I don't change my Dockerfile or only change the end of it, the image rebuilds starting from the start or random places halfway in the Dockerfile. Other times the cache works as expected. I have no `ADD` commands.

The command I am using to build my image is `docker build --tag=pineapple/orange .`

The output starts off like so:

```
Step 1 : FROM centos:7
 ---> 0f0be3675ebb
Step 2 : MAINTAINER Dixie Chicks <DixieChicks@music.com>
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7669f54fc137
Step 3 : RUN yum update &&     yum install -y epel-release &&     yum install -y wget                     git                     python-devel &&     wget "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" &&     python get-pip.py
 ---> Running in 92a8f1cff2db
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: centos.den.host-engine.com
 * extras: centos-mirror.jchost.net
 * updates: centos.chicago.waneq.com
... [starts re-installing everything]
```

Does the build cache not work with an explicit tag? What strategies can I use to figure out why this is happening?

Edit: If it makes a difference, I have been editing the Dockerfile from within PyCharm.

Comment: I only see a single run. What do you mean by inconsistent?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to isolate the first line of a Dockerfile in its own base image:

```
FROM centos
MAINTAINER Dixie Chicks <DixieChicks@music.com>
RUN yum update && \
    yum install -y epel-release && \
    yum install -y wget \
                    git \
                    python-devel && \
    wget "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" && \
    python get-pip.py
```

I build that base image *once*, then I create another Dockerfile which starts from:

```
FROM myBaseImage
```

That way, I can rebuild my second Dockerfile as many time as I want, all the pre-requisite installations are already done (and never recompiled) in the first image.

Answer (score 0):

The cache is based on the delta system (differences).

Yum update and some of the ones in your command will almost never end up with the same delta. All it takes is a third party repo to update for that file to become a different hash. As packages change, the end result will end up different.

It basically can't cache that. Your best bet if you have a specific set of packages to ensure is to do what VonC said and package this up in a pre-requisite container.

This also makes the operations side of me happy when I do it because I know if I build it now vs 7 days from now, I will end up with the same packages. In your example if you built it now and received wget-{version a} you might build it again in the future and get wget-{version b}. Perhaps that version has a difference in flags, or libraries, etc and causes a chain reaction and your app to behave eradically. While rare this is not impossible.

Comment: Good explanation on the yum effect on cache. +1. I didn't have that in my answer.

Comment: I don't think that's true. Docker documentation: "Aside from the ADD and COPY commands, cache checking will not look at the files in the container to determine a cache match. For example, when processing a RUN apt-get -y update command the files updated in the container will not be examined to determine if a cache hit exists. In that case just the command string itself will be used to find a match."

Comment: You may be right, I've seen a few bug tickets to suggest its inconsistent. However looking back on the original question it's hard to see that it should have been cached. Perhaps output from two consecutive runs might help